# Is there a generic paywall service i can integrate in my online service site?

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, plugins, saas

I have a number of websites that offer online services.

Instead of writing my own paywall, I was wondering if there is some service or plugin I can integrate into my sites that does the work. This should include 3 plan configuration with prices and features, and Stripe integration, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few sites that offer plugin/api based paywall service:

- http://piano.io/
- https://www.membergate.com/
- http://pigeonpaywall.com/
- https://www.paywall.com/